Why Quasar PWA + SSR server-rendered source code not work for production build generated code?
I create a from scratch new project based on the latest @quasar/cli.
Unfortunately the PWA + SSR usage mentionned here: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-ssr/ssr-with-pwa/ only work in Development mode and NOT WORK in Production.
As soon as you create a Production build, it's not work anymore.
To resume, inside quasar.config.js (or quasar.config.ts)
For Only SSR case
// ...
ssr: {
    // ...
    pwa: false
    // ...
}
// ...

quasar dev -m ssr produce a source server-side rendering.
quasar build -m ssr then cd dist/ssr then node index.js  produce a source server-side rendering.
but
For PWA + SSR case
// ...
ssr: {
    // ...
    pwa: true
    // ...
}
// ...

quasar dev -m ssr produce a source server-side rendering
quasar build -m ssr then cd dist/ssr then node index.js NOT GENERATE server-side code.
Question: what configuration I missed and I should add, at build time or at running node time, to made server-side rendering work?

Below all the instruction to reproduce the bug:

On Windows 11

With nvm 1.1.12

With node 20.12.0

With npm 10.5.0

Create a quasar directory, and move inside

Run npm i -g @quasar/cli

Run npm init quasar
-- Install create-quasar@1.8.4
-- Choose App with Quasar CLI, let's go!
-- Project folder: quasar-project
-- Pick Quasar version: Quasar v2(Vue 3 | latest and geartest)
-- Choose TypeScript
-- Chose Quasar App CLI with Vite 2 (stable | v1)
-- Package name: quasar-project
-- Project product name: Quasar App
-- Project description: A Quasar Project
-- Author: SkeptRaiser
-- Pick a Vue component style: Composition API
-- Pick your CSS preprocessor: Sass with SCSS syntax
-- Chose Linting / State Management (Pinia) / axios / vue-i18n
-- Pick an ESLint preset: Prettier
-- Install project dependencies? Yes, use npm

Move inside directory quasar-project

Add line "dev-ssr": "quasar dev -m ssr", after "dev" to "$scripts" property under package.json from directory quasar-project

Run npm run dev-ssr

Reach view-source:http://localhost:9100/ and see the source look like following


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US dir=ltr>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module">
import { inject } from "/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime";
inject({
  overlayConfig: {},
  base: "/",
});
</script>
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={};document.currentScript.remove()</script>
    <title>Quasar App</title>

    ...
  </head>
  <body class="desktop no-touch body--light" data-server-rendered>
    <div id="q-app"><div class="q-layout q-layout--standard" style="min-height:0px;" tabindex="-1">...</div></div><script type="module" src="/.quasar/client-entry.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

with a rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

Add line "build-ssr": "quasar build -m ssr" after "build" to "$scripts" property under package.json from directory quasar-project
Run npm run build-ssr
Move inside directory dist/ssr
Run node index.js
Reach view-source:http://localhost:3000/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en-US dir=ltr><head><script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={};document.currentScript.remove()</script> <title>Quasar App</title>...</head><body class="desktop no-touch body--light" data-server-rendered> <div id="q-app"><div class="q-layout q-layout--standard" style="min-height:0px;" tabindex="-1">...</div></div></body></html>

with a rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

Move outside directory and back to quasar-project directory
Change line 144 pwa: false, to pwa: true, in the config ssr: property from file quasar.config.js
Run npm run dev-ssr
Reach view-source:http://localhost:9100/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US dir=ltr>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module">
import { inject } from "/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime";
inject({
  overlayConfig: {},
  base: "/",
});
</script>
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={};document.currentScript.remove()</script>
    <title>Quasar App</title>

    ...
  </head>
  <body class="desktop no-touch body--light" data-server-rendered>
    <div id="q-app"><div class="q-layout q-layout--standard" style="min-height:0px;" tabindex="-1">...</div></div><script type="module" src="/.quasar/client-entry.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

with a rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

Run npm run build-ssr
Move inside directory dist/ssr
Run node index.js
Reach view-source:http://localhost:3000/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en-US dir=ltr><head><script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={};document.currentScript.remove()</script> <title>Quasar App</title>...</head><body class="desktop no-touch body--light" data-server-rendered> <div id="q-app"><div class="q-layout q-layout--standard" style="min-height:0px;" tabindex="-1">...</div></div></body></html>

with a rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

Move outside directory and back to quasar-project directory
Add line "dev-pwa": "quasar dev -m pwa", after "dev" to "$scripts" property under package.json from directory quasar-project
Run npm run dev-pwa
Reach view-source:http://localhost:9200/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module">
import { inject } from "/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime";
inject({
  overlayConfig: {},
  base: "/",
});
</script>

    <title>Quasar App</title>

    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="q-app"></div><script type="module" src="/.quasar/client-entry.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

with a NO rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.



Add line /src-pwa after /src-cordova property under .eslintignore from directory quasar-project


Run npm run dev-ssr
Reach view-source:http://localhost:9150/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US dir=ltr>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module">
import { inject } from "/@vite-plugin-checker-runtime";
inject({
  overlayConfig: {},
  base: "/",
});
</script>
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={};document.currentScript.remove()</script>
    <title>Quasar App</title>

    ...
  </head>
  <body class="desktop no-touch body--light" data-server-rendered>
    <div id="q-app"><div class="q-layout q-layout--standard" style="min-height:0px;" tabindex="-1">...</div></div><script type="module" src="/.quasar/client-entry.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

with a rendered body that is CORRECT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.

Run npm run build-ssr
Move inside directory dist/ssr
Run node index.js
Reach view-source:http://localhost:3000/ and see the source look like following

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Quasar App</title>...</head><body><div id=q-app></div></body></html>

with a NO rendered body that is NOT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR.


Edited answer:
It seems to be linked to the service-worker mechanism itself. If your service-worker not run

then you will see the SSR render code from server under view-source:
But if the service-worker run

The view-source: feature will so you an empty ssr response from server. This behavior not depend on dev or build command but depend on the activation or not of service-worker.
Original answer:
It seems it's a bug with Chrome view-source: feature.
If I use a wget http://localhost:3000/ then I read the index.html file downloaded cat index.html I effectively see the correct rendered code inside the downloaded file.
From Firefox, the view-source: feature show the correct rendered code if you use the reload button front of URL search bar (but if you just reach it, the render is not present and I correctly not know why).
